# twisted python separation of data between protocols

Tags: python, protocols, twisted

According to [twisted documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html)
 a new Protocol instance is created every time a connection is made however i am observing some sort of data sharing between the two.

Briefly I have defined a class that each protocol will use for state

```
class JSONCollector():
    char_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    ...    

    def process_data(self, data):
        ...       
        self.char_buffer.write(char)
```

The protocol instantiates it

```
class JSONProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.json_collector = JSONCollector()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.json_collector.process_data(data)
        self.transport.write(str(self))
```

However each connection seems to get the same instance of JSONCollector, when I added the following statements to dataReceived
            self.transport.write(str(self.json_collector.char_buffer))
            self.transport.write(str(self))

I get the following:

connection 1: StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x968ae2c><**main**.JSONProtocol instance at 0x969036c>

connection 2: StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x968ae2c><**main**.JSONProtocol instance at 0x969068c>

Also everytime I type in text, text that was typed in from other connection(s) gets displayed. 
So it seems that for some strange reason StringIO() instances are shared, am I missing something. I suppose I can use a factory to separate buffers by addr and make sure each Protocol only uses its own buffer, but without having the need for shared storage I would rather not jump through hoops

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
class JSONCollector():
    char_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Seems like an error, and the source of your troubles.  Instead, try this:

```
class JSONCollector():
    def __init__(self):
        self.char_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
```

Otherwise, you are making one `char_buffer` for the entire class type, as opposed to one per instance.

Comment: Well that's just embarrasing